# Chrome extension click bot in webGL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome plugin that will record a series of click and play them back
I have seen that you can simulate a click on a DOM element but the problem is in my case, I only have a webGL canvas and the buttons are not directly accessible

I have managed to get the user's click position using this :

```
document.onclick = function(e)
{
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    console.log(x + " " + y)
    //browser.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "open_new_tab", "url": "aze"});
};
```

But I haven't found anything to use these positions to perform a click action on the page

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you want to simulate a click on the webpage?

JavaScript has the `click()` method exposed for all elements:

```
element.click()
```

If you don't know the element, but just the positions:

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click()
```

You can dispatch a mouse click at a specific position:

```
const = (x, y) => {
  const ev = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true,
    'screenX': x,
    'screenY': y
  })

  const el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

All the above should be done via Content Script within the extension.

Comment: I tried your solution but it seems like even if I put x,y coordinates it still cliks to 0,0 on the screen since the canvas takes the whole screen size
Looks like I can not click on a button that is not accessible by the DOM ?